# Querying a dataframe in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe which has a 3 fields: NAME, CATEGORY, COUNTRY

Now I would like to have all data where the category is the String `over 10 mio` *or* the Country is `Germany` *and* the Country is `Sweden`.

Any recommendation how to "query" my dataFrame in R?

I would appreciate your replies!

Comment: Subsetting is part of every basic tutorial. Read some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use which.

```
desireDf <- df[ which( df$CATEGORY=="over 10 mio" &  (df$COUNTRY=="Germany" | df$COUNTRY=="Sweden" )), ]
```

Also it works without which:

```
desireDf <- df[ (df$CATEGORY=="over 10 mio" &  (df$COUNTRY=="Germany" | df$COUNTRY=="Sweden")), ]
```

Comment: There is no need to use `which`. `[` accepts logical values in i.

Comment: `|` means AND. What is then a logical OR?

Comment: @mrquad, | means OR, & means AND (and so the solution doesn't give you the right answer, it gives you rows with CATEGORY = "over 10 mio" OR COUNTRY="Germany" OR COUNTRY="Sweden")

Comment: | means logical OR, & means logical AND.